# table structure is not coming properly in FF with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one table having 10 rows.Now on page load lets say first 7 rows are showing and I have blocked last 3 rows using jQuery.
Now on click of a span I want to show last 3 rows..its working fine in IE but not in FF.
in FF, when I am loading last 3 rows , the first 7 row css stops working , I mean from 2 nd col, it starts to be right aligned, thus breaking the whole table structure, but the last 3 roes are coming in proper place.

```
 $("tr").slice(index).css("display", "block");
```

I have tried to change the  display prop to table/inline-table..but its of no use.
Can somebody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just setting it to its default by specifying a blank string?

```
$('tr').slice(index).css('display', '')
```

Comment: How Should I thank u :-) :-). Ok vote up and marked as ans . :-)